# Countable subset of $A$ with cluster points in $A$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Trying to prove:

> If $A$ is any subset of $\Bbb R^p$, then there exists a countable subset $C$ of $A$ so that if $x \in A$ and $\epsilon > 0$, then there is an element $z$ of $C$ so that $\|x - z\| < \epsilon$. Hence every element of $A$ is either in $$ or is a cluster point of $C$.

Particularly the existence of $C$. I know that if $A$ is countable, all I have to do is let $C = A$. But I have no idea how to come up with a set like this for uncountable $A$. I'm not even convinced such a set exists if $A = (0, 1)$ in $\Bbb{R}$, since it seems like for any countable $C$ I choose, I can always come up with a small enough $\epsilon$ to make some of $A$ neither an element nor a cluster point of $C$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: Use the fact that there is a countable base $\mathscr{B}$ for the topology of $\Bbb R^n$. Let $$\mathscr{B}_0=\{B\in\mathscr{B}:B\cap A\ne\varnothing\}\;,$$ for each $B\in\mathscr{B}_0$ choose a point $x_B\in B\cap A$, and let $C=\{x_B:B\in\mathscr{B}_0\}$.